# Azure Iot edge tempSensor module displaying old data

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

As part of the tutorials, I first did Azure iot edge deployment on Linux, it is working fine.
But, after this, I deployed tempSensor filter module with python from Visual Studio code, PythonModule is deployed but the D2C messages are still old and there is no filtering happening.
I see the old image for tempSensor keeps poping up showing up old created date on EdgeVM.
I did these below to remove old image, but still it it the same.

1. In Iothub, I removed module through set modules page
2. I removed (using purge) the entire iotedge runtime and re-installed 
       it
3. Removed container and image from docker with no luck
   I want the old image to be removed and when I deploy from Visual studio code, the new filtered messages should be appearing

Comment: Have you configured the route for the modules?

Comment: Hi Jais, please let me know if the answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I did these below to remove old image, but with no luck.

With what you have tried, remove module from azure portal or remove local resources using purge. You need show steps you did or error message or what you see that are not expected, so we can do further investigation.

About how to troubleshoot and get log information you can reference "Common issues and resolutions for Azure IoT Edge".

Here I will show information about how to delete module from azure portal and from local command line. You can compare with what you have done and have a try again. If still not working, feel free post error message etc here.

**[Delete module from azure portal](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/544):**

1. Click on device
2. Click on Set Modules button

[image]

3. Check checkbox next to module
4. Click Delete Button

[image]

5. Click Next

[image]

6. Click Next Again
7. Click Submit
8. You will then see Pending removal

[image]

If your Edge runtime is running on a device, then the module will be removed

[image]

**Delete from local:**

If you want to remove the IoT Edge runtime and related resources from your device, use the following commands.

Remove the IoT Edge runtime.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge iotedge
```

When the IoT Edge runtime is removed, the containers that it created are stopped, but still exist on your device. View all containers.

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

Delete the runtime containers that were created on your device.

```
docker rm -f edgeHub
docker rm -f edgeAgent
```

Delete any additional containers that were listed in the docker ps output by referring to the container names.

Remove the container runtime.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge moby
```

**Add new module to previous deployment:**

If you have edgeAgent, edgeHub and tempSensor modules running. When you want to add a new module like temp sensor filter module you have tried, you can create and build the new module via VS Code and select the edge device and select Create Deployment for IoT Edge device. To view the edge device in VS Code you need install [Azure IoT Edge extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-edge) and then sign in azure. More information and steps you can reference "[deploy and monitor modules from within Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-python-module#deploy-and-run-the-solution)".

**View modules on your device from VS Code:**

Once you've deployed modules to your device, you can view all of them in the Azure IoT Hub Devices section. Select the arrow next to your IoT Edge device to expand it. All the currently running modules are displayed.

If you recently deployed new modules to a device, hover over the Azure IoT Hub Devices section header and select the refresh icon to update the view.